# javascript regular expression matching on very specific search (Searching start of string)

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following regular expression

`/144*/g`

I want it to match 14450, 14445, BUT NOT 14.

What I want is to match the first 3 characters being 144 and anything after that.

```
var zip = '14';//Don't want this to match
var search = new RegExp('144*', 'g');
if (zip.match(search)) //TRUE
```

Comment: Try `144\d+` or `14\d+`

Comment: Why not just  `if (x.substr(0, 3) === "144")`

Comment: something like `/^144\d+$/`

Comment: Should be `/^144.*$/i` as far as I can tell. Is this about 5 digit zip codes? If so, you need `/^144\d\d$/`.

Comment: Chris is in Rochester, so this is definitely about the zip code. Answers should consider this, even if OP didn't mention it, since the variable name and context heavily suggest it.

Comment: I want the users to come up with their own regex. It seems 144.* does what I want

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to match the first 3 characters being 144 and anything after that.

You don't need regex nor string manipulation for this. You can just use [`string.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and check if `144` is at the start (zeroth index) of the string:

```
const isOneFourFour = zip.indexOf('144') === 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex, which will match any text starting with `144` but won't match `14`

```
^(?!14$)144.*$
```

This negative lookahead `(?!14$)` stops matching `14` number and rest all is allowed.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvUeG9/1)**

Negative lookahead is redundant indeed and you can write it as `^144.*$` or `^144\d*$`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `144*` matches 14 and then repeats 0+ times number 4.

That will match for example 14, 144 or 14444444

If you want your match to start with 14 and what follows should be 1 or more digits you could use:

`^144\d+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPZLQ1/1)